# Questions about typedef class

Tags: c++, jvm

Recently, I found some C++ code in OpenJDK 9, like this:

```
typedef class oopDesc * opp;
class oop { /* ... */ }
```

Who can explain the code, I just know about a little of C++.

Comment: There's nothing fancy at all here. Please look at a good book or online reference for `typedef`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is equivalent to:

```
class oopDesc;
using opp = oppDesc*;
```

And the second line is without interest `oop` is not `opp`.

This is horrible code.